# jHipster App crashes propably because CloudFoundry activates cloud profile

Tags: jhipster, cloud-foundry, gitlab-ci

The deployment of my small jhipster App "customerapp" fails and it is probably because cloud foundry sets the profile "cloud" in addition to the profile "dev". I am using several spaces in cloud foundry for the different stages of the development: dev, staging and prod.

I used the jhipster generator, added some entities customer, address and contacts. App is running locally without any issues.

I also use gitlab-ci to build, test and deploy my software. My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this (I deleted some unecessary parts).

```
image: mydockerregistry.xxxxx.de/jutoro/jhipster_test/jhipster-dockerimage

services:
  - docker:dind

cache:
   key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - node_modules
    - .maven

 before_script:
   - chmod +x mvnw
   - export MAVEN_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.maven

 stages:
   - build
   - package
   - deployToCF

 mvn-build:
   stage: build
   only:
    - dev
    - prod
   script: 
     - npm install
     - ./mvnw compile -DskipTests -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME - 
Dspring.profiles.active=dev

 mvn-package-dev:
  stage: package
  only:
    - dev   
  script:
    - npm install    
    - ./mvnw package -Pdev -DskipTests -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
  artifacts:
      paths:
        - target/*.war  

mvn-package-prod:
  stage: package
  only:
    - prod 
  script:    
    - npm install    
    - ./mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
  artifacts:
      paths:
        - target/*.war     

deployToCloudFoundry-dev:
  image: pivotalpa/cf-cli-resource
  stage: deployToCF
  only:
    - dev
  cache:
    paths:
      - bin/
  script:
   - bash ci/scripts/deployToCloudFoundry.sh  

deployToCloudFoundry-prod:
  image: pivotalpa/cf-cli-resource
  stage: deployToCF
  only:
    - prod
  cache:
    paths:
      - bin/
  script:
    - bash ci/scripts/deployToCloudFoundry.sh
```

The DOCKERFILE (which is built and added to our docker repository also with gitlab-ci):

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 1.8.2
FROM openjdk:8
MAINTAINER Robert Zieschang 

RUN apt-get install -y curl
# install node.js
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs python g++ build-essential && \
apt-get clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# install yeoman
RUN npm install -g yo
```

The deplpoyToCloudFoundry.sh shell script:

```
cf login -a $CF_API_ENDPOINT -u $CF_USER -p $CF_PASS -o "${CF_ORG^^}" -s  ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME^^} 
cf push -n $CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

My manifest file:

```
---
applications:
- name: customerapp
  memory: 1024M
  #buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#v3.19.2
  path: target/customerapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
  services:
  - postgresql
  env:
    #SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev
    #SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT: dev
    #JAVA_OPTS: -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

The pipeline runs well, the app is packed into the war file and uploaded to cloud foundry as well, but it crashes and I assume it is because somehow cloud foundry still applies the profile 'cloud' and this overrides important configurations from jhipsters 'dev' profile.

```
 [...]
2019-01-02T19:03:16.05+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-02 18:03:16.055  INFO 8 --- [           main] pertySourceApplicationContextInitializer : 'cloud' property source added
2019-01-02T19:03:16.05+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-02 18:03:16.056  INFO 8 --- [           main] nfigurationApplicationContextInitializer : Reconfiguration enabled
2019-01-02T19:03:16.06+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-02 18:03:16.064  INFO 8 --- [           main] com.jutoro.cco.CustomerappApp            : The following profiles are active: cloud,dev,swagger     
[...]
```

This later leads to:
2019-01-02T19:03:29.17+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-02 18:03:29.172 ERROR 8 --- [           main] com.jutoro.cco.CustomerappApp            : You have misconfigured your application! It should not run with both the 'dev' and 'cloud' profiles at the same time.
[...]

After that cloud foundry stops the app.

```
2019-01-02T19:04:11.09+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 83899f60-78c9-4323-8d3c-e6255086c8a7 stopping instance 74be1834-b656-4445-506c-bdfa
```

The generated application-dev.yml and bootstrap.yml was just modified in some places:

bootstrap.yml

```
        uri: https://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@url.tomy.jhipsterregistryapp/config
        
        name: customerapp
        profile: dev # profile(s) of the property source
        label: config-dev
```

application-dev.yml

```
client:
    service-url:
        defaultZone: https://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@url.tomy.jhipsterregistryapp/eureka/
```

What did I try to set the dev profile in cf:

- added -Dspring.profiles.active=dev in gitlab-ci.yml in addition to -Pdev
- added SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev in the manifest env: section
- added SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT: dev in the manifest env: section
- added SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: {"spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.profiles.active": "dev"} (as mentioned in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2317)
- added JAVA_OPTS: -Dspring.profiles.active=dev in the manifest env: section (cv env customerapp shows that it was set)
- set the JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=dev with cf set-env and cf restage

Any help is appreciated.

Regards
Robert

Comment: You can set `JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '[enabled: false]'` to tell the JBP to disable spring auto reconfiguration, which is what adds the cloud profile. Just be careful as that also disable the auto reconfiguration of services.

Comment: Thank you @DanielMikusa but I do not exactly know, which consequences would lay ahead, if I turn off the autoconfiguration. But I found a way to deploy. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: It depends on your app. For example, you have a single DataSource you can configure it to work locally. Then when you push to CF, the JBP's autoreconfiguration will automagically reconfigure your single DataSource to point to the bound database. It's a little bit magical and has some limitations, so IMO it's better to just use Spring Cloud Connectors directly and explicitly configure your DataSources. If you do that, then disabling autoreconfiguration doesn't really have any impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the answer before. Turns out deep down it was a datasource problem which made the app not respond to the heartbeats.
Uncomment

```
#hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
```

In the application properties fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe any "future" person may stumble upon the same behaviour.

I was able to deploy my jhipster app to cloud foundry. 
I somehow "fixed" it, but I am not aware of further consequences. Yet.

Turned out cloud foundry had a problem to monitor my jhipster app via the standard health-check-type http which should be "heartbeat"?
So I decided to switch the monitoring behaviour to a not heartbeat-ish way.
Just switch health-check-type to process in your manifest.yml file.

```
health-check-type: process
```

The app is now running.

Comment: The drawback of this is that CF won't be able to detect if your application stops working and restart it. With a health check type of "process", all CF looks at is if the process is up and running. As long as the JVM doesn't exit, this will be true. If your app were to hang and stop processing requests, the process would continue running and your app would not be automatically restarted by the platform. If you set health-check-type to "http", the platform will attempt to access an HTTP endpoint from your app (default "/"). If this returns anything but 200 OK, app is restarted automatically.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Mikusa for the clarification. This is not the desired behaviour. So I'll give it a try to turn off auto configuration. Thank you so far.

Comment: Hello Daniel, I removed the health-check-type, added the JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION... The app starts now but nevertheless, the cloud profile is still applied.

    2019-01-14T09:32:24.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     Profile(s):     [cloud, dev, swagger]

Comment: Where/how did you add that? Can you confirm from the output of staging that Auto reconfiguration is not still being installed? When it's installed, you'll see a line from the JBP during staging that specifically says it's installed. I would suggest toggling the change you made on/off and confirming that it's actually disabling auto reconfiguration. Let me know if it's disabled and you're still seeing the cloud profile on.

Comment: My bad. I added it to the env variables. Now autoconfiguration is deactivated. This means my ${vcap. } placeholders for my datasource won't work, right?

Comment: No. Spring Boot provides the `vcap.*` property place holder. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html

Comment: Not to be confused with the `cloud.*` property place holder that I believe is added by the auto reconfiguration. See here -> https://docs.run.pivotal.io/buildpacks/java/configuring-service-connections/spring-service-bindings.html#properties

Comment: Hi Daniel, I finally got it to work. Turns out that deep down it was a problem, that the auto-commit from HikariDataSource was set to false in the application properties but was not recognized by cf somehow. that lead to my app never answering heartbeats. So uncommenting #ibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true fixed the issue. The app started and everything went well. :)
Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you were able to get that sorted out.